# Ajaxrequest doesnt call function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to use Ajax to communicate with a servlet. When i look at the Net tab in firebug, i can see that i get the right response from the server. Despite of that, the Ajaxrequest doesn't seem to be calling my vulAan function. To check if the ajaxrequest calls any function i added window.alert() functions. Only window.alert("request verstuurd") gets called. This is the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("registreerform").observe("submit", controleer);
    $$("input")[1].observe("blur", getVulAan);
    $$("input")[2].observe("blur", getVulAan);
};

function getVulAan(event){

     var post = $$("input")[1].value;
     var huis = $$("input")[2].value;
     if (post && huis) {
     window.alert("request verstuurd");
     event.stop();
     new Ajax.Request (
      "http://www.ntwpracticumnet.ou.nl:8080/registratie/PostcodeServlet",
        { method: "get",
        parameters: {postcode: "1076CT", huisnr: "390"},
        onSucces: vulAan,
        onFailure: nietGelukt,
        onExcepton: nietGelukt
        }
      );
    }
    }
function vulAan(ajax) {
    window.alert("request geaccepteerd");
    var jsWaarde = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    var plaats = jsWaarde.plaats;
    var straat = jsWaarde.straat;
    $$("input")[3].value = plaats;
    $$("input")[4].value = straat;
    }
function nietGelukt () {
    window.alert("niet gelukt");
    }
```

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename `onSucces` to `onSuccess`, check http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Request/

Comment: Your edit is wrong. You cannot replace the event with vulAan() - it will likely pass the response anyway!

Comment: It all works now. It was just a small typing error as Raunak pointed out.

Comment: @user3166227 glad it helped, sometime small mistake gets unnoticed.. Please accept answer if its fine with you.